# Understanding the use of pointers in C language to swap two strings

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop

why is the output of the following code is "pune" ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
 {
char str1[]="bombay";
char str2[]="pune";
char *s1=str1,*s2=str2;
while(*s1++=*s2++);
printf("%s",str1);
printf("\n");
getch();
```

}

Comment: They aren't being swapped.

Comment: But what were you *expecting* the output to be?

Comment: This code `while(*s1++=*s2++);` is unreadable for a start

Answer (score 1):

You are just copying s2 to s1. So it's obvious that the output should be "pune"

Comment: He was lucky that pune is smaller than bombay

Comment: can anyone explain the working of the while loop here?

Comment: Its termination condition is (*s1 == 0) and while this hasn't occured, you are copying each char from s2 to s1 and increment both pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You have written while(*s1++=*s2++); 
The semicolon at the end implies that the while is taken as a statement and not a loop.
so you are trying the copy each char of s2 to s1. So, after copying 'pune' to s1, there is a null character present at the end of s1. Now that null is also copied in to s2. While printing the string s1,  %s will print the string until null is found. Hence you get pune as output.